# 3D Model and texture are pixelated and streched

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I am new to Blender and want to make a floating island 3d model so I started making the rocky bottom part

I followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RQ7PDzPVAc) and this is what I got:

[image]

The model and the textures are too pixelated and streched

The tutorial dude told me to do Unwrap and I did but it still does not look good

What can I do to make it look better?

Here is the blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_xTGWMflZUGOxhISmZIw3c2dS3ntSCL_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please pack your image and share your file so that we can check what's going on: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to BlenderSE! Try adding more vertices or smoothing it maybe.

Comment: You didn't pack the image before uploading it as @moonboots asked. File > External Data > Pack Resources in Blender then save the file (under a different name to your original) and share it again.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here: Your mesh has adjacent faces that are 90° or more, therefore this bad stretching effect. And as you've unwrapped with the basic *Unwrap* mode, the texture ends up wavy because it is how your mesh is.

You could remesh it in *Sculpt* mode in order to clean the topology, press <kbd>R</kbd> to choose the quad size and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to remesh, first remesh with large quads to smooth the whole mesh then with smaller ones to have a denser topology:

[image]

Then find a rock texture and sculpt with the *Stencil*:

[image]

Then unwrap with the *Smart UV Project* mode and paint a rock texture with the *Stencil*.

As for the *Remesh* tool in *Object* mode, go into the *Object Data panel > Remesh > Quad*:

[image]

Comment: but what do I do if I want to make a rough surface and not a smooth surface?

Comment: In that case you first need to clean the topology, you can do it with the Remesh operation in Sculpt mode (R to choose the quad size then Ctrl R), then use a rock image as texture and sculpt?

Comment: I've edited my answer, tell if it helps

Comment: when I press "R" I can only rotate the island

Comment: R in Sculpt mode (in the latest versions of Blender)

Comment: ah thx I am using 3.4 lol

I thought thats the latest

Comment: it should work in 3.4 but you need to be in Sculpt mode

Comment: I am in the Sculpting tab in Sculpt mode in the latest version and using the default keybindings and R still only rotates the island, but you also said I can smooth out the places where the texture is too streched so I am going to do that, thx

Comment: or use the remesh tool in the Object Data panel > Remesh > Quad Remesh

Comment: what is the Object Data Panel?

Comment: See my edit ;)  ..............